# How to make "goto" go to the label that is set by variable using preprocessor?

Tags: c

#### Edit: I am sorry for asking this stupid question. As people have noted, preprocessor handles these in the compilation, so it cannot know what is inside the variable. Doh..

I am programming PIC microcontrollers and I do not have access to the stack. So, in order to create a very simple and easy cooperative multitasking system, I want to try this trick.

I am going to label some of the lines of a function, so that when I come back to the function which is in a loop, I want to continue from where I left.

So, for example, if the **status** is **2**, then the function will have **goto point2;** in its first line and if the **status** is **3**, then the function will have **goto point3;** in its first line etc.

I could not manage to create this. Could anyone lead me to a direction?

```
#define resume_from(x) goto point##x

unsigned char status = 0;
unsigned char x = 0;
unsigned char y = 0;

void my_func(void)
{
    resume_from(status);
point0:
    status = 1;
    return;
point1:
    x++;
    status = 2;
    return;
point2:
    x += 2;
    status = 3;
    return;
point3:
    x += 3;
    status = 0;
}

void main(void)
{
    while (1)
    {
        my_func();
        y++;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's horrible. Use a `switch`.

Comment: `goto`s are resolved at compile time. You just cannot do that.

Comment: Labels and their addresses are decided at compile time. `goto` simply jumps to the appropriate location, which means it can't be told where to go at runtime based on the runtime value of a variable. That's what switches and ifs are for. So either use a table that maps a status code to a function or a big, hairy `switch`.

Comment: @Mat I am already using `switch` for that.. But the code looks to messy.

Comment: Then use separate functions and an array of function pointers.

Comment: @Mat Wouldn't this introduce too much overhead? My PIC microcontroller runs only at 16MHz!

Comment: Benchmark it (with optimizations turned on).

Comment: @Mat - profiling on a PIC is no easy feat, and optimisations may not be possible without paying thousands for the optimising compiler.

Comment: Then just try it out and see if it works. The obvious thing is a switch. If the only problem with that is that you find it "ugly", try writing it prettier.

Answer (score 2):

You may be interested in [continuation passing style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation_passing_style). Probably, [CPC](http://gabriel.kerneis.info/software/cpc/) should interest you. Please notice that CPS transformation is a *whole program* transformation. Read also wikipages on [continuations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation), [coroutines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coroutine), [cooperative multitasking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooperative_multitasking),  [non-preemptive multitasking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonpreemptive_multitasking), [callbacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_%28computer_programming%29) ...

Read Andrew [Appel's old book on *Compiling with Continuations*](http://www.ebook3000.com/-Compiling-with-Continuations--by-Andrew-W--Appel_80709.html) and the more recent paper [Compiling with Continuations, Continued](http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/64044/compilingwithcontinuationscontinued.pdf) by A.Kennedy.

You could use computed [Goto](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goto)-s. In standard C99 it is not possible, but some compilers (notably [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)) provide [labels as values](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Labels-as-Values.html) with indirect `goto` as an extension. This enables [threaded code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Threaded_code) (for interpreters).

I have no idea if your compiler on PIC is giving you all that. Perhaps you should consider implementing your own whole program source to source transformer (or find a language and a compiler more suited to your needs, or develop your own PIC compiler, which is an interesting project as such.
See also [ocapic](http://www.algo-prog.info/ocapic/web/)...).

Perhaps you should consider porting [CPC](http://gabriel.kerneis.info/software/cpc/) to your system or compiler....

#### addenda

your original code

```
 #define resume_from(x) goto point##x
 unsigned char status = 0;
 void my_func(void) {
    resume_from(status);
```

should not even compile. The last line is expanded by the [C preprocessor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor)
as `goto pointstatus;` and you don't have any `pointstatus` label. Try to get the preprocessed form (e.g. with `gcc -C -E` or the equivalent). You probably want a `switch` or a computed goto (if your compiler gives you that).

Comment: *I have no idea if your compiler on PIC is giving you all that* — doubtful but possible. Microchip's compilers for recent chips are GCC based, but can't do everything. Compiling as `gnu99` is possible though. If it's an older PIC... probably not.

Comment: Isn't continuation passing style inappropriate for C? I thought it depended on having lexically-scoped identifiers (closures), which C doesn't.

Comment: @Steve314: CPS requires a whole program transformation, see the papers on CPC ....